# RxJs: get array of observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have following pseudocode

```
zip(
        ...[1, 2, 3].map((id) =>
          this.http.function1(id).pipe(
            mergeMap((obj1) => this.http.function2(obj1.id)),
            mergeMap((obj2) => this.http.function3(obj2.id)),
          ),
        ),
      ).subscribe((result) => {
        console.log('This should be an array of all the results of the requests to this.http.function3');
      });
```

I want the result of all the request together. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `zip()`, I would emit each value of the array using `from()`, then at the end of your pipe, you can apply `toArray()` to combine all emitted values to an array after all HTTP requests have completed.

```
from([1, 2, 3]).pipe(
  mergeMap(id =>
    this.http.function1(id).pipe(
      mergeMap(obj1 => this.http.function2(obj1.id)),
      mergeMap(obj2 => this.http.function3(obj2.id))
    )
  ),
  toArray()
).subscribe(result=>{
  console.log('Result should now be an array from function3', result);
});
```